# Shift + F10 right-clicks on my machine, but this shortcut is not in xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml, so how does it work?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, xubuntu, xfce4, ubuntu-22.04

I hold incompatible beliefs. I believe that:

1. `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml` lists every keyboard shortcut on my machine.
2. `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml` does not declare that I have any keyboard shortcuts that require both <kbd>Shift</kbd> and an F key.
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> very obviously trigger a right-click.

Which of my beliefs is false? I suspect it's #1, but if so, where on my Xubuntu 22.04 machine lists these shortcuts?

Comment: Shift+F10 seems to be a GTK key ([link](https://xfce.xfce.narkive.com/r5mBOLTg/any-way-to-delete-the-alt-shift-f10-keyboard-shortcut)).

Comment: You can give it a look ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/219977/66388)). Search for `shift+F10` instead of F10. And yes, it seems that not all the shortcuts are listed there, but maybe they can be overruled from there...

Comment: @Hastur Very useful, but it's not there.

Comment: @harrymc Seems very plausible, but I can't fathom a way to confirm that's the case on my system.

Comment: Have you looked in `~/.gtkrc-2.0`?

Comment: @harrymc I've checked multiple places and found nothing of relevance.

Comment: Try [this method](https://scot.tg/2010/04/07/debugging-step-over-f10-eclipse-ubuntu/) to look into `/desktop/gnome/interface`. Try also [this one](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1077127#p1077127).

Comment: @harrymc No luck. `gconf-editor` is not in my repositories and I have no `/desktop/gnome/` folder. There are other `.gtkrc-2.0` files on my machine, but there is no `~/.gtkrc-2.0`.

Comment: Have you tried to add `unbind  "<shift>F10"` as in my link to whatever `.gtkrc-2.0` files you have?

Comment: @harrymc Yes. No effect.